# Inconsistent error response in .NET 6 Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

I am not able to find how to throw exceptions as they are generated by .NET 6 Web API.
If I return `BadRequest(ModelState)` with added errors I am not getting same message with status, type, title etc.
By default .NET generates this kind of errors when validation error occurs:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-488f8c0057223cbba92fc1fbfc8865d8-2341d7aba29d098f-00",
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON object contains a trailing comma at the end which is not supported in this mode. Change the reader options. Path: $ | LineNumber: 7 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
    ],
    "model": [
        "The model field is required."
    ]
}
```

}

I want to configure my application to respond with the same error JSON, or I want to configure so it will respond with the custom JSON fields.

I tried to add a middleware that will catch exceptions, but it does not handle model errors (which are handled by framework by itself). How can I handle errors globally, or how can I throw exceptions that will be treated the same as framework handles them? Any documentation/tutorial links are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable default bad request responses like the following code:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
     options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

So you can return any model you want in `BadRequest`.
However, you then have to do the model validation yourself in each endpoint like:

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Post1")]
public IActionResult Post1(Model1 model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(new CustomApiResponse());
   ...
}

[HttpPost(Name = "Post2")]
public IActionResult Post2(Model2 model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(new CustomApiResponse());
   ...
}
```

If you want to return a global JSON structure, you can create a filter with the [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and use it for all your endpoints so you don't need to do model validation on every endpoint.

Custom Validation Filter:

```
public class CustomValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new GlobalApiResponse());
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

You need to register your custom filter in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomValidationFilterAttribute));
});
```

This is just one of the ways you can use to achieve what you want, you can find different methods on the internet.

Comment: BTW, I assume you are using the Minimal API, since you mentioned using .NET 6 Web API. It's possible you are not using it, and if you want I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I started with MVC application, then removed views. I think it will work for me, I will try it later and reply to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net6 Web Api, If You Want To Validate Model By Your Code, And You Can Debug It, Just Do This:

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new BaseResponse() { code = ResponseCode.失败, msg = "" });
        }
        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

Then Do It In The Program.cs

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    //Add Your Filter
    options.Filters.Add<ModelValidationFilterAttribute>();
}).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    //Disable The Default
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```